# Weird behavior in Artifactory download when using JFrog CLI

Tags: devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I found this really weird behavior when using the JFrog CLI for downloading. 
Ok let's start from uploading: When I want to upload a complete directory hierarchy, say I have this structure:

```
root
│
└───Folder1
    └───Folder2
        │   file1
        │   file2
        │   file3
        │
        └───Folder3
                nested1
                nested2
                nested3
```

And I want to upload the contents of `Folder2` (While my location is at root!) and all its subdirectories and files into `MyRepo/MyPath', so my repo will look like:

```
MyRepo
    └───MyPath
        │   file1
        │   file2
        │   file3
        │
        └───Folder3
                nested1
                nested2
                nested3
```

If i'll try this:

```
jfrog rt upload --flat=false Folder1/Folder2/ MyRepo/MyPath/
```

I'll be left with `Folder1/Folder2` in my hierarchy in Artifactory, and that's not what I want, so I use placeholders:

I'll execute the following command:

```
jfrog rt upload --flat=false "Folder1/Folder2/(*)" MyRepo/MyPath/{1}
```

That works well, and I can understand the logic: `--flat=false` is so that the `nested*` files will remain in the `Folder3` directory, whereas the `file*` files will be in the `Folder2` directory, and the
placeholders say: Take whatever is in `Folder1/Folder2` and copy it to `MyRepo/MyPath`. Perfect!

Trying to do the inverse, i.e. download, using the same logic: Say I want to download everything under `MyPath` into `Folder1/Folder2` directory I'm at, so i'll get the first structure drawn above,
I try this:

```
jfrog rt download --flat=flase "MyRepo/MyPath/(*)" Folder1/Folder2/{1}
```

But that creates a really weird directory structure which I don't even want to draw here. The solution was to use `flat=true` instead of `flat=false` which is really unintuitive and not-understood at all. Can someone explain this behavior or at least direct me to whoever in JFrog I need to report this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug. I have just filed this bug here - https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/883

The issue is specific to the placeholders feature. JFrog CLI seems to misinterpret the correct definition of --flat, when it is used together with placeholders in the "jfrog rt download" command. I believe this issue will be worked on very soon.

Thanks a lot for sharing this!